# No module named lxml.html

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, pip, lxml

Running OS X 10.9.4, I'm trying to use Scrapy, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 3, in <module>
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 8, in <module>
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 6, in <module>
from scrapy.core.engine import ExecutionEngine
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 14, in <module>
from scrapy.core.downloader import Downloader
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from .middleware import DownloaderMiddlewareManager
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 7, in <module>
from scrapy.http import Request, Response
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 9, in <module>
import lxml.html
```

And 'pip install lxml' only returns

```
/Users/username/.virtualenvs/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you installed `scrapy` with system version of Python.

While you installed `lxml` in virtualenv version of Python.

Check your `pip` reference which python using following command:

```
pip -V
```

---

If you want install `scapy` in virtualenv, you need to uninstall `scrapy` first. Otherwise it will prevent running of virtualenv version because of PATH issue.

```
deactive  # deactive first, to use system version of python/pip
pip uninstall -y scrapy
hash -r   # refresh program location.
```

Comment: I think you're right, it returns:
pip 1.5 from /Users/username/.virtualenvs/scraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
How do I resolve it?

Comment: @mobius, Which python do you want to use?

Comment: @mobius, If you want virtualenv one, install `scrapy` there: `pip install scrapy`

Comment: @mobius, I meant  (system version / virtualenv version).

Comment: @mobius, If you want to use system version, deactivate virtualenv first, then install lxml: `deactivate; pip install lxml`

Comment: Ah, virtualenv version. So I uninstall Scrapy, then reinstalled while in my virtualenv (just to make sure), but I'm still getting "ImportError: No module named lxml.html".

Comment: @mobius, What do you get by issuing following command: `type scrapy`

Comment: "scrapy is /usr/local/bin/scrapy". Also, I updated the output I get after installing Scrapy inside the virtualenv

Comment: @mobius, Uninstall `scrapy` from the system-wide version first. `deactive; pip uninstall -y scrapy; hash -r`.

Comment: That worked! I think I understand what was going wrong